# Is that possible to add another platform auth in firebase default auth ui?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm using firebase auth.
What I want to do is using another platform auth in firebase default auth.
The default auth platforms are composed of "google", "email", "phone", "twitter", "yahoo", "ms" and so on.
In here, I want to add a kakao talk, but there is no way to do.
Is there any way to do this?

the link about this is here

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui?hl=en

Comment: For every other provider you have to use custom tokens (you will need an external Webservice).

Comment: Yes I know I have to enroll external service token when I add another platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FirebaseUI libraries are open-source, so you can add any provider you want to it by forking the repo and making the necessary changes.

But first you'll need to allow your users to sign in with the custom provider (regardless of the UI). To learn how to allow that, have a look at the Firebase documentation on [using a custom auth system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth).

Comment: There is no way but changing the firebase ui code and using it internal module. Thanks for your answer.